# strace associate parent pid to child pid

Tags: linux, system-calls, strace

I'm tracing an application by running:

```
strace -f -y -qq -z -etrace=execve,... -o app.trace ./app
```

is there a way to identify which process spawned which child_process ?

My goal is to construct a graph that encodes the hierarchical relationship of (sub)processes for further analysis of the syscalls.

EDIT: 
Here a more concrete example:
given the following hierarchy of processes:

```
p1
|
.---.
|   |
p2  p3
    |
    p4
```

I identify that p2 and p4 trigger syscalls of interest using strace.
Now I'd like to find the closest common ancestor, which in this case is p1.

Is it possible to create a dump that has all the information using `strace`, or do I have to use `ps`/`pstree` in parallel?

EDIT2:

I was not able to instrument `pstree` for my problem.
`pstree` seems to only give you a snapshot and many of my processes are very short lived making it impossible to reliably catch all of them by calling `pstree` repeatedly.

EDIT3:
I've noticed following entries in my trace:

```
23901 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=23902, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
```

Process `23901` logs `SIGCHLD` signal with `si_pid=23902`. 
does it imply that process `23901` created childprocess `23902` ?

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://superuser.com/questions/363169/ps-how-can-i-recursively-get-all-child-process-for-a-given-pid

Comment: I think the command `pstree` already gives the kind of output that you are aiming to get by writing a utility by yourself. Do check it in detail.

Comment: If the dump (strace log?) includes the fork syscalls and you follow child processes i think you could look at the two return values (one in parent and one in child process) of the fork syscall to create a tree

Comment: negativ. execve which spawns a new child_process does not use fork and its return code is zero on success

Comment: to be more explicit, my application does not use `fork`.

Comment: execve does not spawn a new process. fork, vfork, posix_spawn, and clone do.

Comment: If your application does not use `fork`, does it create child processes by another mean ? (eg: `clone`)

Comment: Does it create threads in a single process ? What do you want to track exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

You should track the calls to `clone`. It tells who spawns who.